# Passing 2 or more parameters from a HTML form to a PHP function

Tags: php, html, forms, function, parameters

So, I have a HTML form and I need to send it's value as a parameter to a php function, but I also need a different value, that's not even inside the HTML.

For example:

```
<form action="methods.php" method="register"> 
   <input type="text" placeholder="EventID"> 
   <input type="submit" value="Register"> 
</form>
```

This form would get the event id and send it as a parameter to register the user into the event. But I need to send the user as a parameter also (`function register($user, $eventid)`) and I have no idea on how to do so.

I did find some similar things around here, but they were related to POST and GET and I'm not sure they work for me and I could not understand how to use in them in my case, so if anyone could help me out, pleaaaaaase, i'd be really thankful

Comment: Use AJAX for sure. But really, there are tons of examples of what you're asking all over the internet. Values are send by name in old school form submission, which you should not be using... again... use AJAX. Every submission I've ever done involves POST or GET.

Comment: I was not able to find one I could understand what to do ):
I've never used AJAX before, but if you believe it'll work, I'll do some googling and try to use it, thanks :D

Comment: It's sort of complicated. You may want to use jQuery... but I'll throw you a raw example below. Hold on.

Comment: Is the user already logged in? Or can he sign-up with any user name?

Comment: what do you mean by method="register"??? it should be either get or post only

Comment: Yes, the user is logged in, I'd get the user from a cookie, for now

Comment: I need to register the user into the event that the user (that is logged in) inputed the id. I'm calling the function register from the methods.php, só I can register the user in the event
but in this way I'm doing, I can only pass the eventid as a parameter, but I also need the user...

Answer (score 0):

Look for the explanation in comments below:

```js
//<![CDATA[
// external.js
var post, doc, bod, htm, C, E, T; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){ // load

// used in post function below to create String from Object
function phpEncode(obj){
  var r = [];
  if(obj instanceof Array){
    for(var i=0,l=obj.length; i<l; i++){
      r.push(phpEncode(obj[i]));
    }
    return '%5B'+r.join(',')+'%5D';
  }
  else if(typeof obj === 'object' && obj){
    for(var i in obj){
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        var v = obj[i], s;
        if(typeof v === 'object' && v){
          s = encodeURIComponent('"'+i.replace('"', '\\"')+'":')+phpEncode(v);
        }
        else{
          v = typeof v === 'string' ? '"'+v.replace('"', '\"')+'"' : v;
          s = encodeURIComponent('"'+i.replace('"', '\\"')+'":'+v);
        }
        r.push(s);
      }
    }
    return '%7B'+r.join(',')+'%7D';
  }
  else{
    r = typeof obj === 'string' ? '"'+obj.replace('"', '\\"')+'"' : obj;
    return ''+r;
  }
}
// used in post function below to evaluate (make into code) JSON String that comes back from PHP
function phpAccept(url){
  return eval('('+decodeURIComponent(url)+')');
}
// here is an example of a post AJAX function
post = function(send, where, success, context){
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  var c = context || this;
  x.open('POST', where); x.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  x.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(x.readyState === 4 && x.status === 200){
      if(success)success.call(c, phpAccept(x.responseText));
    }
  }
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    var r = [];
    for(var p in send){
      r.push(encodeURIComponent(p)+'='+phpEncode(send[p]));
    }
    x.send(r.join('&'));
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send must be an Object');
  }
  return x;
}
// yes, you can do this - just remember that non-primitive values are the actual Object through assingment
doc = document; bod = doc.body; htm = doc.documentElement;
// simple way to create an Element by tag
C = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
// simple way to document.getElementById()
E = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
T = function(tag){
  return doc.getElementsByTagName(tag);
}
var form = E('form'), sub = E('sub'), i1 = E('i1'), i2 = E('i2');
// prevent old school submission
form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault(); // prevents submission
});
// just for testing remove below
var tS = E('test_out').style;
// remove above
// ajax submisson
sub.addEventListener('click', function(){
  /* note that if the Elements are not removed from or added
     to the DOM you don't need to get them again Element.value
     will probably be different so you'll want to get them
     on every click
  */
  post({phpProp1:i1.value, phpProp2:i2.value}, 'yourPHPajaxResponsePage.php', function(data){
    /* before data comes back yourPHPajaxResponsePage.php may look like this:
    <?php
    session_start(); // super common - read up on it - not needed here - but won't hurt
    if(isset($_POST['phpProp1'], $_POST['phpProp2'])){
      // usually you affect MySQL using PHP at this point
      // we'll just send them back in this lame example
      $res = array('jsProp1' => $_POST['phpProp1'], 'jsProp2' => $_POST['phpProp2']);
      // makes results come back as JSON
      echo json_encode($res);
    }
    ?>
    */
    if(data){ // may want more conditions
      E('out').innerHTML = data.jsProp1+'<br />'+data.jsProp2;
    }
  }, this);
  // just for testing - remove below
  tS.display = 'block';
  E('temp_res').innerHTML = i1.value+'<br />'+i2.value;
  // remove above
});
// testing only remove below
var ins = doc.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
for(var i=0,l=ins.length; i<l; i++){
  ins[i].addEventListener('focus', function(){
    tS.display = 'none';
  });
}
// remove above
form.addEventListener('keydown', function(ev){
   // if user hits enter
  if(ev.keyCode === 13)sub.click();
});

}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
.main{
  width:980px; margin:0 auto;
}
#form{
  width:266px; color:#fff; background:green; padding:10px; 
}
#form>div>label{
  display:block; float:left; width:57px;
}
#form>div>input{
  width:203px;
}
#form>div{
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
#form>#sub{
  display:block; margin:0 auto;
}
/* remove below - testing only */
#test_out{
  display:none;
}
#test_out>div:first-child{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <title>AJAX Example</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <form id='form'>
      <div><label for='i1'>Input 1</label><input id='i1' name='i1' type='text' value='' /></div>
      <div><label for='i2'>Input 2</label><input id='i2' name='i2' type='text' value='' /></div>
      <input id='sub' type='button' value='submit' />
    </form>
    <div id='out'></div>
    <!-- for testing remove below -->
    <div id='test_out'><div>Must have PHPServer code in JavaScript Comments to get real results</div><div id='temp_res'></div></div>
    <!-- remove above -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What do you think?

Comment: gosh, you did a lot of coding there hahahah i'm really thankful for the time you took to help me
I'll take a look at it by the weekend to take the proper time to analyze it and understand it :D  
I'll let to know if manage to make it work
thank you so much ^^

Comment: It will probably take you a while to wrap your head around this stuff, if you're new to it. If you're a newbie you might want to ignore `phpEncode`, until you think you're ready to take on recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple you just need to take care of few things.

1: every input field should have a name.

2: set form method either GET(to send values visible in the url) or POST(to send data without showing in the url)

3: on methods.php receive form data if send via GET then $_GET['input_field_name']  or via POST then $_POST['input_field_name']

Comment: The thing is, I do not have the user as a field, only the eventId

Answer (score 0):

you can use hidden field or you can use session or cookie for user

```
<form action="methods.php" method="post"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="txtuser" value="abc"> 
   <input type="text" placeholder="EventID"> 
   <input type="submit" value="Register"> 
</form>
```

if you use cookie or session then there is not need to pass it as parameter its a global variable so you can access its value at any page directly, you just need to store value to it and access it any where in your project.

Comment: i was actually going to use cookies for now, but anyway I do not know ow to get the user from there and pass it as a parameter

Comment: if you use cookie or session then there is not need to pass it as parameter its a global variable so you can access its value at any page directly, you just need to store value to it and access it any where in your project.