# Passing PHP integer variable value to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I need to pass variable from php to javascript.
Yes, I have read couple of questions on StackOverflow and tried many possibilities. Still no success.

I recently used following code for passing value:

```
<?php $num= 1970; ?>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
var num = "<?php echo $num; ?>";
</script>
```

(I used it without `echo` too - no way).
I'm trying value saved in variable `$num` pass to

```
            [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 26), 0.25],
            [Date.UTC(num , 11, 6), 0],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 20), 1.41],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 25), 1.64],
            [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 4), 1.6],
```

This solution doesn't work, obviously.

Comment: Just remove the quotes around your PHP tags.

Comment: Have you tried using your brower's "View Page Source" option to see what the JS looks like *after* the PHP has been applied? Sometimes that makes it obvious what's wrong with the server-side code.

Comment: Your code seems fine ... did you get any error in javascript syntax above this code ....

Comment: @VeshrajJoshi no errors, I don't absolutely know what am I doing wrong

Comment: Are you expecting `var num` to stay as 1970, or are you expecting a change in that number to be held by PHP?

Comment: @PHPglue Actually, it will cooperate with mysql server -  so yeah, it will change.

Comment: Look at my example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43220572/passing-2-or-more-parameters-from-a-html-form-to-a-php-function/43220963#43220963).

Comment: how is `var num` being used? What makes you think it doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var num = "<?php echo $num; ?>";
```

to

```
var num = <?php echo $num; ?>;
```

Of course, you should know that PHP executes before the page is sent to a Browser, so if you're looking for this to happen dynamically look into AJAX.

Comment: PHP can't pass values to JavaScript without AJAX. It can build Web Pages by creating Strings that produce HTML, JavaScript, and CSS, though..

Comment: I left some stuff out. See this, now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43220572/passing-2-or-more-parameters-from-a-html-form-to-a-php-function/43220963#43220963

Answer (score -1):

You can physically write the PHP code to the DOM, and then use JavaScript to target the DOM element:

```
<?php
$num = 1970;
echo "<div id='num'>" . $num . "</div>"; // <div id='num'>1970</div>
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var num = parseInt(document.getElementById('num').innerHTML);
console.log(num); // 1970
</script>

<style>
#num {
  display: none; /* Hide the element */
}
</style>
```

This way you can access the PHP variable without the JavaScript needing to be coded into the PHP file itself.

I've also created a working example of this through [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/djvf-9sa8).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: What about the `.value`? That would be a String anyways.

Comment: *"What you need"* - You don't *need* to do it this way, though obviously this is an option.

Comment: Fixed both of those concerns.

Comment: @user7303261 - Define "*doesn't work*". It should work exactly as expected. What problem are you having?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Well, page doesn't even load.

Comment: I just tested the code above, and it works as expected in my local environment. Are you sure you added the CSS in `<style>` tags? That may be what is causing the page to break.

Comment: @ObsidianAge wow, yeah you are right, it works. Can you explain me what does the "comment" part behind `//` mean?

Comment: That's just standard PHP and JavaScript comments; I just wrote comments to signify what your output would be at the various stages :) And glad to hear this solution appears to have worked for you. Once you've confirmed this solution solves your problem, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge Of course, i know comments. The weird thing is it reacts to the value in(!) the comment part between `>` and `<` signs. If I change `// <div id='num'>1970</div>` to `// <div id='num'>1975</div>` the chart changes according to this - doesn't matter what value is saved in a line above.

Comment: @user7303261 - It's not supposed to, and doesn't do that in my local environment. I can only assume you somehow accidentally copied the comment in the echo itself (so it output the DIV twice), or have some weird parser that is killing the `/` character. The comments are only for ease of clarity anyway, so simply remove them in your actual application :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge Well, I removed the whole comment and It doesn't work again. :(

Comment: Then undo your changes until you get it working again? The code above definitely works; I have **proven** that in the [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/djvf-9sa8). If you cannot replicate that, then the issue is definitely either with your environment or some other code on your page that is conflicting.

Answer (score -1):

you can echo javascript in php

```
<?php $num= 1970; 

    echo"<script>alert('$num');</script>";
?>
```